# I need help solving an unexpected Teams adaptive card error

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I woke up this morning and started receiving this error with my incoming webhook

*Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400 with ContextId 01=2..
*

My adaptive card & webhook have been working for months, I have not recently changed anything yet the randomly started receiving this error.

Here is my card setup:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "contentUrl": null,
            "content": {
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.5",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": "{{215595441__response__content}}",
                        "wrap": true,
                        "size": "Medium",
                        "weight": "Medium",
                        "separator": true
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "Container",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "ColumnSet",
                                "columns": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "Column",
                                        "width": "auto",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Image",
                                                "url": "{{214806744__data__image__url}}",
                                                "size": "Medium",
                                                "style": "default"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "type": "Column",
                                        "width": "stretch",
                                        "verticalContentAlignment": "center",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                                "text": "{{214806744__data__title}}",
                                                "weight": "Bolder",
                                                "size": "Medium",
                                                "wrap": true
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "text": "{{214806744__data__description}}",
                                "wrap": true,
                                "size": "Default"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "TextBlock",
                                "text": "Sent By: {{214806743__userName}}",
                                "wrap": true,
                                "size": "Small",
                                "weight": "Lighter",
                                "spacing": "Medium"
                            }
                        ],
                        "style": "emphasis",
                        "bleed": true
                    }
                ],
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
                        "title": "Open URL",
                        "url": "{{214806744__data__url}}",
                        "style": "positive"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I triggered the incoming webhook and expected it to post to Teams. Instead, I received the above error.

HARDCODED JSON USED:

{
"type": "message",
"attachments": [
{
"contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
"contentUrl": null,
"content": {
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"version": "1.5",
"body": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "lorem ipsum",
"wrap": true,
"size": "Medium",
"weight": "Medium",
"separator": true
},
{
"type": "Container",
"items": [
{
"type": "ColumnSet",
"columns": [
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "auto",
"items": [
{
"type": "Image",
"url": "https://colourlex.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/vine-black-painted-swatch.jpg",
"size": "Medium",
"style": "default"
}
]
},
{
"type": "Column",
"width": "stretch",
"verticalContentAlignment": "center",
"items": [
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "lorem ipsum",
"weight": "Bolder",
"size": "Medium",
"wrap": true
}
]
}
]
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum",
"wrap": true,
"size": "Default"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Sent By: Benn, G",
"wrap": true,
"size": "Small",
"weight": "Lighter",
"spacing": "Medium"
}
],
"style": "emphasis",
"bleed": true
}
],
"actions": [
{
"type": "Action.OpenUrl",
"title": "Open URL",
"url": "https://www.wsj.com/business/autos/a-free-world-champion-to-rival-china-nippon-chiefs-ambitions-for-u-s-steel-deal-598a9585?mod=hp_lead_pos3",
"style": "positive"
}
]
}
}
]
}

Comment: We tried to repro this issue by replacing the dynamic values of the card JSON with static random values and it works fine for us. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZ8pV.png There might be some issue with the dynamic values, that's why it's giving the error message. Please do verify that.

Comment: I tested with hard coded values, still getting this error

Comment: A webhook message delivery failure with error 400 usually indicates that the payload sent to the Microsoft Teams endpoint is invalid. This could be due to a formatting issue or because the payload exceeds the size limit. Please verify the payload and make sure it is properly formatted and within the size limit.